# Trouble with prime number program in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly language on x86 and made a simple programe that will tell number is prime or not.

I think I am doing right but still not getting the desired result,below is code

```
section .bss
b db
section .data
x db "Number is Prime",10,0
y db "Number is not Prime",10,0
z db "value is=%d",10,0

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
mov eax,17
mov ebx,2
loop:
mov [b],eax
div ebx
mov eax,[b]
cmp edx,0
jz Print_not_Prime
inc ebx

 cmp ebx,17
 jnz loop
 push x
 call printf
 add esp,4
 ret

 Print_not_Prime:
 push y
 call printf
 add esp,4
 ret
```

In above code I am checking with number 17 and output of programe telling its not prime number.

Could anybody let me know where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two problems with this:

```
b db
....
mov [b],eax
```

You're only reserving space for a byte at `b` but storing a dword (4 bytes). You should use `dd` instead of `db`.

---

```
div ebx
```

You should use `cdq` (or `xor edx,edx`) prior to `div` in order to clear `edx`, since this division will divide `edx:eax` by `ebx`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer but why we really need to clean the edx prior to div,anyway old value in edx is getting overwritten with new value everytime div is called.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar It is overwritten, but `div` takes it's operand from both registers in case you want to divide a number that doesn't fit into a 32-bit register. Allows you to divide up to 128-bit numbers in 64-bit mode. Same reason why `imul` outputs to two registers. Multiplying two 64-bit integers can potentially yield a 128-bit long number.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for the response but could you please explain it in more simpler way.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar If you multiply a `n`-bit number with an `m`-bit number then the result will be a `n+m -1`-bit number. So the result from multiplying two 32-bit registers potentially won't fit into a single 32-bit register. As a result the `imul` instruction outputs to two resgisters. In order to be fully reversible `div` accepts two registers as input, always.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: `div ebx` is dividing  the _64-bit_ number in `edx:eax` by `ebx`. That's why the value of `edx` prior to the division matters.

Comment: From above explainations, I got to understand that I need to set register edx to zero because div Inst performs (edx:eax)/(ebx).if edx is not equal to Zero m then edx:eax combination would be a unexpected. suppose I am performing an operation like 17/2 and I am not setting edx to Zero then in next iteration it will become one and effective div operation would become 18/2 and will get unexpected result.Is my understanding is correct ??

Comment: `1:17` is not 18, it's 4294967313 (1 * 2^32 + 17).

Answer (score 2):

You need to zero `edx` before each divide. The dividend for `div` comes as a double-register operand in `edx:eax`.

If you have a remainder in there from the last trial division then it will screw up your results.

Also it's better to store your dividend in a register (`ecx`, `esi`, `edi` are still unused) or at least on the stack then in memory which as Michael pointed out is insufficient to store a dword.